# Formatting fractions in front in PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, string-manipulation

I have this Plot:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 3 Sin[x], Sin[x]/2}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

In the graphic result, there is `sin(x)/2`

Is there a way to change it in `1/2 sin(x)`?

Comment: The simplest way is to set the legend manually, and type in the form that you prefer.

Comment: @Szabolcs If I am not in the Plot function, but I am somewhere else, is there a way to do that? And by the way, how can I set the legend manually?

Comment: You can use `PlotLegends -> {Sin[x], 3 Sin[x], HoldForm[1/2] Sin[x]}`.  I do not understand your other question: "If I am not in the Plot function, but I am somewhere else"

Comment: @Szabolcs I think you answer that, nominating HoldForm

Comment: @Szabolcs I meant if i would like to write somewhere 1/2*sin[x] and not sin[x]/2

Comment: @Szabolcs by the way, Plot[{Sin[x], 3 Sin[x], Sin[x]/2}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Sin[x], 3 Sin[x], HoldForm[1/2]* Sin[x]}] seems not working

Comment: That is because `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` must be removed first ...

Comment: Ok thank you, that can be considered as an aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways.

**1.** We post-process the output. One has to take care, since we change the expression, that the result makes sense.  The `$excludedForms` indicate expressions not to be altered.  For a general purpose function, this might be quite long.  For the OP's problem it need only be `_Graphics`.

```
$excludedForms = _Graphics | _Graphics3D  (* |_Rule|_InterpolatingFunction etc. *); 
fractionForm = # /.
  {x : $excludedForms :> x, HoldPattern[Times][c__?NumericQ, r__] :> Row[{c, r}, " "]} &;
```

**2.** This is more general, but overrides the built-in formatting process for `Times`.

```
ClearAll[fractionForm];
fractionForm /: MakeBoxes[fractionForm[expr_], form_] :=     
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Times},
  Unprotect[Times]; 
  Times /: MakeBoxes[HoldPattern[Times][c__?NumericQ, r__], f_] := 
    MakeBoxes[Row[{c, r}, " "], f];
  Protect[Times];
  MakeBoxes[expr, form]
  ];
```

In both cases, we get this:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 3 Sin[x], Sin[x]/2}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}
  ] // fractionForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

This does it automatically for this example.

```
exp = {Sin[x], 3 Sin[x], Sin[x]/2};
Plot[exp, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}, 
 PlotLegends -> (exp /. Rational[a_, b_] :> HoldForm[a/b]), 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

No idea how generally this will work.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 3 Sin[x], Sin[x]/2}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"sin(x)", "3 sin(x)", "1/2 sin(x)"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]